# Draw a node as a square with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I googled but cannot find a solution. Is that possible to draw a node with Ti*k*Z which will be a square and NOT a rectangle of arbitrary proportions?

Minimum working example can be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) [circle,draw] (c100) {$c_{100}$};
        \node at (3,0) [rectangle,draw] (v100) {$v_{100}$};
        \draw (c100) -- (v100);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While circle is perfectly round, rectangle is just a rectangle:

[image: Circle and rectangular nodes with TikZ]

And I want it to be a square. I did not find any shape like *square* or so.

Comment: Actually, that's impossible since every square [IS a rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle#Squared.2C_perfect.2C_and_other_tiled_rectangles), what you want is an [Oblong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblong).

Comment: No, what I want is NOT oblong :)

Comment: I cannot edit anymore, I meant what you want to say, not what you've requested.

Comment: I mean, of course, every square is also a rectangle - but I think it's perfectly understandable what was the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult. In the following code, I've defined a custom node shape `square` that inherits from the `rectangle` shape, but forces its size to be square. Unfortunately, the inheritance mechanism doesn't allow redefinition of inherited saved anchors, so I had to copy some code from the TikZ `rectangle` definition.

On the plus side, it should be correct in all cases (defining different values for `inner [xy]sep`, `minimum {width,height}` and `outer [xy]sep`) and has all the anchors of the `rectangle shape`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% the contents of \squarecorner were mostly stolen from pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
\def\squarecorner#1{
    % Calculate x
    %
    % First, is width < minimum width?
    \pgf@x=\the\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by 2\pgf@xc%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xb%
        % yes, too small. Enlarge...
        \pgf@x=\pgf@xb%
    \fi%
    % Calculate y
    %
    % First, is height+depth < minimum height?
    \pgf@y=\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y by 2\pgf@yc%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@y<\pgf@yb%
        % yes, too small. Enlarge...
        \pgf@y=\pgf@yb%
    \fi%
    %
    % this \ifdim is the actual part that makes the node dimensions square.
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@y%
        \pgf@x=\pgf@y%
    \else
        \pgf@y=\pgf@x%
    \fi
    %
    % Now, calculate right border: .5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox + .5 \pgf@x + #1outer sep
    \pgf@x=#1.5\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@x by.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by#1\pgf@xa%
    % Now, calculate upper border: .5\ht-.5\dp + .5 \pgf@y + #1outer sep
    \pgf@y=#1.5\pgf@y%
    \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y by#1\pgf@ya%
}
\makeatother

\pgfdeclareshape{square}{
    \savedanchor\northeast{\squarecorner{}}
    \savedanchor\southwest{\squarecorner{-}}

    \foreach \x in {east,west} \foreach \y in {north,mid,base,south} {
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\y\space\x}
    }
    \foreach \x in {east,west,north,mid,base,south,center,text} {
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\x}
    }
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,square] {square with rectangular node text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: unbelievably exciting result]

Comment: This looks like the most precise solution. But of course, not the easiest one :) Well, once put in the doc it is then easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

Use the `regular polygon` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library. As Alenanno mentions in a comment, you can define your own style to reduce the verbosity.

I don't know how the size of that is calculated, there is a lot of whitespace in it. Setting `inner sep` to a negative value can reduce the size, but the value has to be modified depending on the length of the node label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
        \node at (0,0) [circle,draw] (c100) {$c_{100}$};
        \node at (3,0) [square,draw] (v100) {$v_{100}$};
        \node at (3,-5) [square,inner sep=-1.3em,draw] {a much longer node label};
        \node at (3,-5) [circle,draw] {a much longer node label};
        \draw (c100) -- (v100);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems like a good solution. Except that I need to write such a long phrase each time -- `regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4`. Is there a way to define a shortcut?

And also the square is bigger than a circle with the same label - is there a way to make it have smaller inside margins?

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka Define a tikz style (using `\tikzset`) like `mysquare/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4, inner sep=0}`, then just add `mysquare` to the nodes you want to affect. For the size, `inner sep=0` solves it.

Comment: Perfect! I put style definition `\tikzset{square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,inner sep=0}}` in the beginning of the document as I am going to use it a lot. Inner separator of 0 seems to be okay for not too big shapes. Thanks guys!

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka I'd also add another style like `every node/.style={draw}` so they are all drawn by default. If you want to have one that is not drawn, just add `draw=none` to the exception node.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution, not mentioned so far. The idea is to set the desired node as a circle, but don't draw it. Then use the `fit` tikz library to draw a rectangle which 'fits' around the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) [circle,draw] (c100) {$c_{100}$};
        \node at (3,0) [circle] (v100) {$v_{100}$};
        \node [rectangle,draw,fit=(v100),inner sep=0] {};
        \draw (c100) -- (v100);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: square-node]

Comment: This is a lovely trick.

Answer (score 8):

Use `minimum size=` which changes both `height` and `width` which you can change singularly as well. Also, keep in mind that `rectangle` is the default shape, so no need to specify it.

Writing `\node at (3,0) [minimum size=1cm,draw] (v100) {$v_{100}$};` you should get

[image]

Comment: This might be good starting workaround. However, as far as I understand, I should manually find a size which fits the node's label. Because if, say, it is $v_{100000000}$ the node will become rectangular again.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution. It uses `width` function to define node's size. As the same parameter is used as `node contents` and size delimiter, node's name and position must be declared before options or inside options.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        [square/.style={%
            draw,
            minimum width=width("#1"),
            minimum height=width("#1")+2*\pgfshapeinnerysep,
            node contents={#1}}]

        \node at (0,0) [circle,draw] (c100) {$c_{100}$};
        \node at (3,0) (v100) [square={$v_{100}$}];
%or
%       \node (v100) at (3,0)[square={$v_{100}$}];
%or
%       \node at (3,0) [square={$v_{100}$}, name=v100];
%or
%       \node[square={$v_{100}$}, name=v100, at={(3,0)}];

        \node at (2,-3) (B) [square=a much longer node text];
        \draw (c100) -- (v100);
          \draw (B.south west) -- ++(45:6cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution (altough I wonder whether a future version of TikZ can just have the `rectangle` shape respect the aspect ratio related options). One corner case that doesn't work: `\node[square=I];`

Comment: @wrtlprnft Yes I must admit that this solution only works when text horizontal component is larger than vertical one. Which doesn't happens with `I`.

Comment: How about `/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetmacro\squaresize{max(width("#1") + 2 * \pgfshapeinnerxsep, height("#1") + depth("#1") + 2 * \pgfshapeinnerysep)}},minimum size=\squaresize`? Unfortunately, directly passing the expression to `minimum size` didn't work, hence the macro definition.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is based in [Graham501617's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559836/1952). It uses a not drawn `circle` node which is  drawn as an square with help of an extra path inside an `append after command` option:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    square/.style={%
        draw=none,
        circle,
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra \draw[black] (\tikzlastnode.north-|\tikzlastnode.west) rectangle 
                (\tikzlastnode.south-|\tikzlastnode.east);\endpgfextra}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) [circle,draw] (c100) {$c_{100}$};
        \node [square] at (3,0) (v100) {$v_{100}$};
        \draw (c100) -- (v100);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update: square customization*

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    square/.style={%
        draw=none,
        circle,
        append after command={%
            \pgfextra \draw[#1] (\tikzlastnode.north-|\tikzlastnode.west) rectangle 
                (\tikzlastnode.south-|\tikzlastnode.east);\endpgfextra}
    },
    square/.default=black
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) [circle,draw] (c100) {$c_{100}$};
        \node [square={red, ultra thick, fill=red!30}] at (3,0) (v100) {$v_{100}$};
        \draw (c100) -- (v100);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a very elegant way

Comment: Is there any pgfkeys hack that could be made to the style to make options apply to the rectangle rather than the circle? E.g. to get `\node [square,red] ...` to apply the red colour to the square.

Comment: @Graham501617 Take a look at new definition, hope it helps. Now `square` accepts one parameter to change its aspect. if you want to change the text (color, font, ...) use something like `\node[square={fill=red}, font=\sffamily, green] {xxx};`