# Passing special characters to “shorthand” x+y options in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-shape

**Update**: this is now a [bug report on sf.net](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/390/).

I think I understand the rules for special characters in `pgfkeys` key arguments: If it contains any of {`,`, `=`, `]`}, it must be protected by putting the entire argument in braces. In that case, the braces are stripped by `pgfkeys` and anything inside is preserved, including surrounding whitespace.

Now, I have the following MWE using `minimum {width,height,size}` as a representative trio:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

 \tikzset{minimum width= {max(1,2)} } % (1) works
%\tikzset{minimum width=  max(1,2)  } % (2) doesn't work because of comma
%\tikzset{minimum size =  max(1,2)  } % (3) doesn't work (expected)
%\tikzset{minimum size = {max(1,2)} } % (4) doesn't work (but I think it should)
%\tikzset{minimum size ={{max(1,2)}}} % (5) doesn't work (desperate attempt)

\begin{document}\end{document}
```

It's clear to me that (2) and (3) can't work because that will confuse the parser. I can explain why (4) doesn't work by looking at the definition in `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`:

```
\pgfset{minimum size/.style={/pgf/minimum width=#1,/pgf/minimum height=#1}}
```

By substituting the argument with stripped braces, which is now `max(1,2)`, for `#1`, we get invalid `pgfkeys` syntax. Everything works as expected if I change the definition to

```
\pgfset{minimum size/.style={/pgf/minimum width={#1},/pgf/minimum height={#1}}}
```

. Is this a bug in the `shapes` module or does this change have a drawback I didn't see?

As a side note, I tried (5) as a workaround, but that also doesn't work. Why?

---

If a more practical MWE is desired: I was originally messing around with [Draw a node as a square with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300098/draw-a-node-as-a-square-with-tikz) and got to the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{square/.style={
    minimum width={max(width("#1") + 2 * \pgfshapeinnerxsep, height("#1") + depth("#1") + 2 * \pgfshapeinnerysep)},
    minimum height={max(width("#1") + 2 * \pgfshapeinnerxsep, height("#1") + depth("#1") + 2 * \pgfshapeinnerysep)},
    node contents={#1},
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,square=Hello];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to use `minimum size` to avoid duplicating the expression.

Comment: I don't think you show sufficient desperation, young padawan.  It works if you try `\tikzset{minimum size ={{{{{{max(1,2)}}}}}}}`.

Comment: Also worked: `\tikzset{minimum size ={{max(1,2)}{}}}` (the empty group prevents the inner braces from being stripped by macro parameter expansion).

Comment: Last one (for now): `\tikzset{minimum size =max{(1,2)}}`.  A quick check with `\pgfmathparse` shows that `max{(1,2)}` works as it should.

Comment: @LoopSpace: So I guess at most five levels of braces get stripped by `pgfkeys`, leaving the innermost level for the second pass? Why ever more than one and why is there an upper limit? Of course, my main question (is this a bug in the `shapes` module?) still remains open, but thanks for the workarounds.

Comment: Found another one: `\tikzset{/pgf/minimum size ={{{{max(1,2)}}}}}` (that's two fewer braces).  Without the `/pgf/` prefix, it tries `/tikz/minimum size` first and when that doesn't work it gets passed to `/pgf/minimum size` and presumably that strips off another couple of braces.  So I guess the point is that these keys get bounced around quite a bit in the key handling and lots of braces get stripped off (and I suspect it would be hard to ensure that they didn't).  I think your fix for `pgfmodule.shapes.code.tex` would be the "right" answer.

Comment: Of course, you can always overwrite the definition of `minimum size` in your own preamble.

Comment: @LoopSpace: I just found a [bug on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/369/) that deals with the brace stripping part. If I don't magically get another answer here, I guess I'll file a bug for the "right" answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Sounds a reasonable plan.  By the way, I think that the protection of `]` is more to do with the fact that keys are often set in the optional argument to a `tikzpicture` environment or drawing command and so any `]` needs protecting otherwise it is taken as the ending square bracket.

Comment: I wouldn't call these as bugs as we discussed in the linked question because then you are leaving all the TeX quirks on the programmer desperately trying to figure out how many groups it has nested into etc. though can be fixed with some more (or less brace pairs on the user side) I think with a language like TeX that's unfair given that having a math parser automatically understanding the context is already pretty cool feature. There will be no end to this as you can always construct cases as @LoopSpace did where it would fail.

Comment: @percusse: I don't quite know what your comment is referring to. I didn't file the sf.net bug I linked to, and if the truth is that we should not relying on any number of surrounding braces to survive `pgfkeys` that's fine with me. But always forwarding arguments with `key={#1}` seems like a safe thing to do. Also, the error happens long before any math parsing takes place, but it's cool that `pgfmath` appears to be very tolerant of braces :-)

Comment: @wrtlprnft It's on the bug report backlinked to another TeX-SX question.

Comment: It certainly seems worth suggesting the modification in this particular case. Maybe there's a good reason not to do that and pushing the responsibility onto the user can't be helped. But maybe there's not, in which case the symmetry with `minimum width` itself favours the change. These things are complicated and it may well be that the response is that fixing this would either create other problems or require far too much by way of overhead etc. But that's not a reason not to file it - just a reason to be open to the developers declining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from suggestions in comments, mine is

```
\tikzset{
    square/.style={
        /utils/exec={
            \pgfmathsetmacro\mysize{
                max(width("#1")+2*\pgfshapeinnerxsep,
                    height("#1")+depth("#1")+2*\pgfshapeinnerysep)
            }
        },
        minimum width=\mysize,
        minimum height=\mysize,
        node contents={#1}
    }
}
```

And the reason is simple: even if you can pass a complicated math expression as the argument, it will be calculated multiple times and waste some time.

Besides, the same math expression does not give the identical result from time to time. An interesting example is

```
\tikz\draw circle(rnd);
```

Is it a circle? or ellipse?

## Comment

Yes, it is a bug. It should have use `={#1}` instead.

A brutal search of `\=\#\d\,` over the whole PGF gives the following results

- > ```
  > \tikzset{radius/.style={/tikz/x radius=#1,/tikz/y radius=#1}}
  > ```
- > ```
  > \tikzset{cs/radius/.style={/tikz/cs/x radius=#1,/tikz/cs/y radius=#1}}
  > ```
- > ```
  > verbose/.style={
  >   verbose IO=#1,
  >   verbose optimize=#1,
  >   verbose up to date=#1,
  > },
  > ```
- > ```
  > \def\tikz@lib@chainin@#1[#2]{\path[late options={name=#1,on chain,every chain in/.try,#2}]}
  > ```
- > ```
  > shape start size/.style={%
  >   shape start width=#1,
  >   shape start height=#1%
  > },%
  > shape end size/.style={%
  >   shape end width=#1,
  >   shape end height=#1%
  > },%
  > shape size/.style={%
  >   shape start size=#1,
  >   shape end size=#1%
  > },%
  > shape width/.style={%
  >   shape start width=#1,
  >   shape end width=#1
  > },
  > shape height/.style={%
  >   shape start height=#1,
  >   shape end height=#1
  > }
  > ```
- > ```
  > trapezium angle/.style={
  >   /pgf/trapezium left angle=#1,
  >   /pgf/trapezium right angle=#1
  > },%
  > ```
- > ```
  > \pgfkeys{/pgf/chamfered rectangle sep/.style={%
  >   /pgf/chamfered rectangle xsep=#1,/pgf/chamfered rectangle ysep=#1}%
  > }
  > ```
- > ```
  > zerofill/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=#1,/pgf/number format/sci zerofill=#1},
  > ```
- > ```
  > radius/.style={start radius=#1,end radius=#1},
  > ```
- > ```
  > /pgf/segment amplitude/.style={/pgf/decoration={amplitude=#1,shape height=2*#1}},
  > ```
- > ```
  > /pgf/segment object length/.style={/pgf/decoration={shape width=#1,radius=#1}}}
  > ```
- > ```
  > inner sep/.style={/pgf/inner xsep=#1,/pgf/inner ysep=#1},
  > ```
- > ```
  > minimum size/.style={/pgf/minimum width=#1,/pgf/minimum height=#1},
  > ```

Some results from `.def` files and datavisualization library are omitted. I am not saying that those lines above contain bugs. But it might be fun to try. One might also want to try `\=\#\d\}` and `\=\#\d.*\,`

Have fun

Comment: `rnd` is an exception. It is called twice once for x radius and once for y radius.

Comment: @percusse no it is not. That is just a funny example to emphasize my point. Back to OP's example: `height` is not stable because it is implicitly affected by font settings; `\pgfshapeinnerysep` is not stable either. Nonetheless I have to admit that in this case it is almost impossible to produce different result.

Comment: I mean implicitly you are calling rnd twice. In your recent example it's just depending on the font size because the units are font dependent. But still the same quantity. That's different than what I mean.

Comment: That's definitely a practical solution. The node text is still set at least four times, so of course it's still not a performance miracle. I still believe that the behavior of `minimum size` is a bug.

Comment: @wrtlprnft please see my update