# How can I re-create this table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, linguistics, layout, phonetic

I would like to re-create the table below in LaTeX.

It's an A4 paper in landscape orientation.

[image]

The way I did it in LibreOffice Writer was using nested tables that have their borders hidden. In the following image you can see the hidden table borders:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to recreate this document in LaTeX. I don't necessarily want to use tables with hidden borders. If there is a different way of doing it by using some kind of positioning that would be great. I just used tables because I see no other way to create the layout in LibreOffice.

Can you give me some suggestions that may help me start and what packages should I consider using? My goal is to export the final LaTeX document to PDF. It has to be a one page document (A4 / landscape). I would be grateful for any suggestion.

I can create two paralel tables, one for vowels and one for consonants.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}

\begin{document}
    % Vowels
    \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        Vowels & Vowels \\
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    % Consonants
    \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        Consonants & Consonants \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I have no idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: You can start here: https://www.latex-tables.com

Comment: Thank you. The website doesn't allow me to create nested tables and as you can see my layout is more complex.

Comment: You not need nested tables, two paralel table should be sufficient (left for vowels, right for consonant). You should show us what you try so far ....

Comment: I can create two paralel tables, see my updated post, but I'm not sure how to create those black squares and position them and also title them.

Comment: You could use `TikZ` for that. I'll post an example as an answer (more flexibility in formatting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example with `tabularx`and an approach very different to a table, with `multicols`. Note that in this case the mechanism to balance columns and  vertical glues act  against the horizontal aligns of the columns even when there are apparently the same number of lines, that could be a dis/advantage depending on your specific needs.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol,tabulary,tabularx}
\def\mg#1{\colorbox{gray!20}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\strut #1}}}
\def\mb#1{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{white}\strut #1}}}
\def\empty{\mbox{\strut}\par}
\def\R#1#2{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\strut #2}}
\def\N#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{white}\strut #1}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

{
\sffamily\bfseries\parskip 1ex plus 0ex minus 1ex
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{15}X}
\addlinespace
\R{7}{VOWELS} & & \R{7}{CONSONANTS} 
\\\addlinespace
\R{5}{The simple words} && \R{1}{The Diphtongs}  & &  \R{3}{Stop Consonants} &&  \R{3}{The Glide Sounds}  
\\\addlinespace
& \N{a} && \N{b} &&& \N{aa}  &&  \R{1}{Voiceless} && \R{1}{Voiced} &&  \R{1}{Voiceless} && \R{1}{Voiced}
\\\addlinespace
& \N{c} && \N{d} &&& \N{bb} & &  \N{p} && \N{b} && \N{h}  && \N{a} 
\\\addlinespace
& \N{d} && \N{e} &&& \N{cc} & & \R{3}{Continuant Consonats}  
\\\addlinespace\addlinespace
\end{tabularx}}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\sffamily\bfseries\parskip 1ex plus 0ex minus 1ex
\setlength\columnsep{2em}\raggedbottom
\begin{multicols}{2}
\centering
\mg{VOWELS}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\mg{The Simple Vowels}

\mb{a}\quad
\mb{b}\par
\mb{c}\quad
\mb{d}\par
\mb{e}\quad
\mb{f}\par
\mb{g}\quad
\mb{h}\par
\mb{i}\quad
\mb{j}\par
\newcolumn
\mg{The Diphtongs}\par
\mb{aa}\par
\mb{ae}\par
\empty
\mb{ai}\par
\mb{ao}\par
\end{multicols}
\phantom{}
\newcolumn\par
\mg{CONSONANTS}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\mg{Stop Consonants}\par
\begin{multicols}{2}
\mg{Voiceless}\par
\mb{p}\par
\mb{t}\par
\mb{k}\par
\newcolumn
\mg{Voiced}\par
\mb{b}\par
\mb{d}\par
\mb{g}\par
\end{multicols}
\mg{Continuant Consonants}\par
\begin{multicols}{2}
\mb{f}\par
\newcolumn
\mb{v}\par
\end{multicols}
\newcolumn
\mg{The Glide Sounds}\par
\begin{multicols}{2}
\mg{Voiceless}\par
\mb{h}\par
\newcolumn
\mg{Voiced}\par
\mb{r}\par
\mb{l}\par
\mb{w}\par
\empty
\end{multicols}
\end{multicols}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your example. I only need two main columns, one on the left and one on the right. Is it possible to re-create my structure I posted in my main post and without the lorem ipsum text?

Comment: for some reason the `\newcolumn` doesn't seem to work for me. It says: `Undefined control sequence. ^^I^^I^^I^^I\newcolumn`

Comment: @ZoltanKing To delete the dummy text just remove the `\lipsum` commands and the lipsum package in the preamble.   If \newcolumn is undefined, most probably you have wrongly removed the multicol package.

Comment: There is something wrong with the `multicol` package, that's for sure. I'm using the latest version of Fedora GNU/Linux with the `tex-scheme-small`. `Mulicol` is part of that `scheme-small` package and when a package is missing I just use the package manager to install them`sudo dnf install tex-packagename`.

Comment: It seems to me that `\newcolumn` can be replaced with `\vfill\null` followed by `\columnbreak`

Comment: I don't understand why is slightly more space added below the title "The Glide Sounds" when using the multicols approach than below "Stop Consonants". Even in your picture it is noticable. In other words, those "Voiceless" "Voiced" titles from column one don't align with "Voiceless" "Voiced" from column two.

Comment: As I said, there are mechanism to balance height of columns and spaces within each column, as paragraph skips in normal text, without taking into account what is external to the column. Thus,  align lines from different columns is from hard to impossible, since unlike in tables, there are not really rows across columns (it is only a visual effect).  If align is a must, then a tabular-like environment is the right approach.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with the tabularx approach is that the titles like "The Simple Vowels" and "Diphtongs" are smaller in height than "Voiceless" and "Voiced". BTW, thank you for your support. I appreciate your time.

Comment: This is because "Voiceless"" cell must take the height of  cells with taller black boxes, but you can increase the cell height in all headings replacing `\strut` in \R definition  by some like `\rule{0pt}{3ex}`,  or in  all cells, using `\extrarowheight1ex` or `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` before the table.

Answer (score 6):

*Seems you chose to have phonetic symbols as white letters on black background. This might look not so good when printing with an inkjet-printer.*

If you like going the painful route you can do it only by placing `\hbox`es and `\vtop`s—for the phonetic symbols I used the tipa-package but I cannot give warranties that I got everything right.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

% ---- Layout ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%      The code for changing the layout is not of importance to you.
%      It is messy and only suits the need of having this example fit on one page
\pagestyle{plain}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth-3cm
\evensidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\marginparsep=2mm
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr1.5cm-2\marginparsep\relax
\textheight=\paperheight
\advance\textheight-3cm
\topmargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{0123456789}%
 \global\footskip=\dimexpr .75cm -.5\dp\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
                               +.5\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\relax
}%
\parindent=0pt
\flushbottom
% ---- END OF LAYOUT ---------------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.06}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\newlength\mycolumnsep
\setlength\mycolumnsep{2em}
\newbox\scratchbox

\newcommand\sethboxwidth[1]{%
  \setbox\scratchbox=\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt #1}%
}%
\newcommand\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth[2]{%
  \hbox{\colorbox{#1}{\hbox to\wd\scratchbox{\hfill#2\hfill}}}%
}%
\newcommand\centeredhboxofsetwidth[1]{%
  \hbox to\wd\scratchbox{\hfill#1\hfill}%
}%
\newcommand\surroundbox[3]{%
  \sethboxwidth{\hbox{#3}}\wd\scratchbox=\dimexpr\wd\scratchbox-2\fboxsep\relax\hbox{#1}\kern#2\relax\hbox{#3}%
}%
\newcommand\phoneticbox[1]{%
   \vbox{%
     \kern.25\baselineskip
     \hbox{%
       \colorbox{black}{\hbox to 3ex{\hfill\textcolor{white}{\vphantom{XVIpg}\textipa{#1}}\hfill}}%
     }%
   }%
}%

\begin{document}

\par
\sffamily
\hbox{%
\vtop{%
  \surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\Large VOWELS}}}{.5\baselineskip}{%
    \sethboxwidth{%
      \hbox{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg} The Simple Vowels}}%
      \hbox{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg} The Diphthongs}}%
    }%
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}The Simple Vowels}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{@}\hfill\phoneticbox{A}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{2}\hfill\phoneticbox{O}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{i}\hfill\phoneticbox{U}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{\normalfont\textsci}\hfill\phoneticbox{u}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{E}\hfill\phoneticbox{@r}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{\ae}\hfill\phoneticbox{\textrevepsilon r}}%
      }%
      \kern\mycolumnsep
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}The Diphthongs}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{e\normalfont\textsci}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{a\normalfont\textsci}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{oU}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{aU}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{O\normalfont\textsci}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\kern\mycolumnsep
\vtop{%
\surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\Large CONSONANTS}}}{.5\baselineskip}{%
\hbox{%
\vtop{%
  \surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}Stop Consonants}}}{.25\baselineskip}{%
    \sethboxwidth{%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
    }%
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{p}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{t}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{k}}%
      }%
      \kern\mycolumnsep
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{b}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{d}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{g}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \kern.375\baselineskip
  \surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}Continuant Consonants}}}{.25\baselineskip}{%
    \sethboxwidth{%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
    }%
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{f}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{\texttheta}}%
      }%
      \kern\mycolumnsep
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{v}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{D}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \kern.375\baselineskip
  \surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}The Sibilant Sounds}}}{.25\baselineskip}{%
    \sethboxwidth{%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
    }%
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{s}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{\textesh}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{t\textesh}}%
      }%
      \kern\mycolumnsep
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{z}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{Z}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{dZ}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
}%
\kern\mycolumnsep
\hbox{%
\vtop{%
  \surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}The Glide Sounds}}}{.25\baselineskip}{%
    \sethboxwidth{%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
    }%
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{h}}%
      }%
      \kern\mycolumnsep
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phantom{\phoneticbox{x}}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{r}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{l}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{w}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{j}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \kern.375\baselineskip
  \surroundbox{\centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{\vphantom{XVIpg}The Nasal Sounds}}}{.25\baselineskip}{%
    \sethboxwidth{%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
      \hbox{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
    }%
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiceless~~}}%
      }%
      \kern\mycolumnsep
      \vtop{%
        \centeredcolorboxofsetwidth{mylightgray}{\textbf{~~Voiced~~}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{m}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{n}}%
        \centeredhboxofsetwidth{\phoneticbox{N}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
}%
}%
}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate your time. Do I need to use TIPA package if I decide to go with XeLaTeX and an IPA supporting font such as Charis SIL? As far as I know in that situation I just need to load the fontspec package with the proper font then I can type the phonetics symbols as-is, without TIPA package. Also, why did you say "going the painful route" ? Isn't your example the best way of doing it?

Comment: Is there a way to set a manual width in `surroundbox`? I need the IPA chart to fill the page like so: https://ibb.co/LdG9WLB so the vowels column need to be larger in width. I  use `\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}`

Comment: @ZoltanKing You don't need the TIPA package if you have other methods of obtaining the phonetic symbols you need. In this case adjust the `\phoneticbox`-command not to use the `\textipa`-macro but to call whatever routine you need to turn `\phoneticbox`'s `#1` into the phonetic symbol you need. I used TIPA in order not to be bound to a specific TeX-engine like XeLaTeX because in your question no TeX-engine was specified. || I said "painful" because while writing the code you need to keep track of the mode (horizontal/vertical) in which TeX is when processing the thing you currently write  ...

Comment: @ZoltanKing ...the thing you currently write  and how things like `\hbox`, `\kern`, `\vtop` behave in which mode. You can easily loose oversight. Someone who is not a "veteran" at these things may quickly find it tiring.  ||  My example is not the best way, because it should be only an outline of how do get the job done by nesting boxes. Nesting boxes can quickly be more confusing than nesting tables. || `\surroundbox` has three arguments: The material in the third argument is packed into a `\hbox` but not typeset yet. The width of this `\hbox` minus two `\fboxsep` is provided as ...

Comment: @ZoltanKing ... is provided as `\wd\scratchbox`. The material in the first argument is typesetset as `\hbox`. Here you can set e.g. a `\colorbox` of width `\wd\scratchbox` where then again two `\fboxsep` are added. After the `\hbox` there is a `\kern`, i.e., a gap corresponding to the second argument. When TeX is in vertical mode, this gap is vertical. Then the `\hbox` with the material of the third argument is actually typeset. This way the material of the first argument is typeset before typesetting the material material of the third argument. ...

Comment: @ZoltanKing ... argument. But at the time of typesetting the material of the first argument, information is already available about the width that the material of the third argument will have when being typeset.

Comment: @ZoltanKing In order to fill the page, you can, e.g., adjust the fonts:
Instead of `\sffamily`, say, e.g., `\sffamily\Large`.  
If you do that, instead of `\Large VOWELS` and `\Large CONSONANTS` say, e.g., `\huge VOWELS` and `\huge CONSONANTS`.  
Additionally you can adjust `\mycolumnsep` which denotes the width of the white horizontal gap between columns of the table.

Comment: Thank you. Your example may not be the best way of doing it but it works and the final PDF is what matters to me. I appreciate your time. I was wondering if there is a way to add a little space (padding) at the top and bottom for titles such "Vowels", "The Simple Vowels", "Consonants"? at the moment the gray box touches the letters at the top and bottom.

Comment: @ZoltanKing E.g., you can add a `\strut` or a rule of predefined height and depth and zero-width to the phrases "Vowels" , "The Simple Vowels", "Consonants" etc. Probably you can do this within the definition of `\surroundbox`, where `\hbox{#1}` is delivered: Do something like `\hbox{\strut#1}` or instead of `\strut` use a `\vrule height x pt width 0pt depth y pt`, x and y denoting measures  ...

Answer (score 2):

To draw your boxes, something like this might work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\rectangle[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
{   \node[shape=rectangle,fill=black,
     text=white,draw,line width=1.5pt,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}
}

\rectangle{\huge ð}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect squares, as opposed to rectangles, are surprisingly difficult, however: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300098/draw-a-node-as-a-square-with-tikz

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about using the `tikz` package however I need the same layout as I posted in my main post which has equal sized squares. I also need those headings such as "simple vowels", "diphthongs", etc. I can't imagine having all these without creating nested tables, even though @zarko mentioned I only need two tables one for vowels and one for consonants. I'm a bit confused at this point.